# Vungle SDK Windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, vungle-ads

I'm trying use Vungle to add Video for my app.
[enter link description here](https://support.vungle.com/hc/en-us/articles/211339368-Get-started-with-Vungle-Windows-SDK)

But i have 2 bug below:
[1](https://support.vungle.com/hc/en-us/articles/211339368-Get-started-with-Vungle-Windows-SDK): Error  1   Cannot await 'Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation`1<string>' 
[2]:Error   2   The type 'Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation`1' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'.

Anyone know, what thing i must do to fix that bug !

Comment: maybe try adding the missing reference?

Answer (score 1):

The reason this isn't working is that Vungle's Windows SDK doesn't currently support 8.1 (Only Windows 10). This should be available by mid-December though.

Comment: Whether I can upgrade from windows phone 8.1 runtime to windows 10 ?